# Calculate if a digital signature is valid

Tags: public-key, signature

In the book *An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography*, it mentions a section on digital signatures and a theoretical example. I am having difficulty understanding the book and I was wondering if someone could better explain how you would be able to deduce if a signature is valid rather than finding what the signature is.

For example, $N = 1562501$ and the public key is $e = 87953$, the document $m = 161153$, and the signature is $d = 870099$. Is there a technique to find if it's a valid signature?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does RSA signature verification work?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-rsa-signature-verification-work)

Comment: While the question was about signatures methods in general, the actual example given is a toy implementation of RSA.  Perhaps if you reviewed the http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9896/how-does-rsa-signature-verification-work/9897#9897 answer, it may address some of your questions (unless you need something more basic; don't worry, we won't be offended by basic questions...)

Comment: Fact: $870099^{87953}\bmod1562501$ is easy to compute, and is $161153$; but computing $870099$ from the other three values is harder, and requires factoring $1562501$, or comparable effort [revised].

Answer (score 1):

Basically RSA signatures work just like encryption but with the keys exchanged.
If somebody tells you $m^{sk}$ you can easily test if
$$
(m^{sk})^{pk} \equiv m\ (mod\ N)
$$
but you cannot calculate $m^{sk}$ yourself.

The problem/trick is the usual, exponentiation is easy but logarithm is hard.

(I like using $sk$/$pk$ for secret-/public-key rather than $d$/$e$ for decryption-/encryption-key as it makes more sense for signatures.)

Comment: The RSA private key operation is not a logarithm; RSA is not: exponentiation is easy but logarithm is hard.

Comment: I don't understand your comment so let me rephrase: Calculating the discrete logarithm of $m^{sk}$ to base $m$ aka the secret key is hard while taking $m^{sk}$ to the power $pk$ and thus verifying the signature is easy.

Comment: @Erwin: a logarithm would be "given $a, b, n$ compute $x$ such that $a^x = b \pmod n$.  Instead, the RSA problem is the $e$-th root; that is, given $b, e, n$ compute $x$ such that $x^e = b \pmod n$

Comment: But in case of signatures the message $m$ is given as is $m^{sk}$. So calculating $sk$ would be calculating the discrete log of $m^{sk}$ to the base $m$.

Comment: However, breaking RSA doesn't require us to recover the value of $sk$; recovering $m$ given $m^e$ would suffice to break both RSA public key encryption and RSA signatures (and there's no known proof that performing $e$-th roots (for odd $e$) can allow us to compute $sk$)

Comment: Breaking the discrete logarithm modulo $N$ of unknown factorization would indeed break RSA; but the RSA problem is of different nature, and we have no proof that it is not easier. In particular, in the discrete logarithm problem, one is not given the equivalent of $e$ in RSA. That knowledge of $e$ makes the RSA problem modulo any known prime trivial, when the discrete logarithm modulo that prime could be hard.

Comment: @poncho You are of course both right. I was just trying to state in simple terms that you can calculate $sig^{pk}$ but you cannot calculate $log_m(sig)$. And indeed since the question was about creating signatures it should be added that calculating $\sqrt[pk]{m}$ would also be hard.