# RSA Digital Signatures Verification

Tags: rsa, signature

I am trying to learn about RSA digital signatures, and have a question about the verification process.

My understanding of the set-up is the following:

The signer chooses two secret primes $p$ and $q$, and a verification exponent $e$ satisfying $\gcd(e,(p-1)(q-1))=1$, then publishes $N=pq$ and $e$.

The signer computes the secret signing exponent $d$ such that
$$de\equiv1\pmod{(p-1)(q-1)},$$

signs the document $D$ by computing $$S\equiv D^d\pmod N,$$ and sends $D$ and $S$ to the verifier.

Here is what I am having a trouble.

I read that the verifier computes $$S^e \pmod N$$ and compares the result to $D$.
If the result is indeed equal to $D$, then the verifier is convinced that the signature is valid. My question is, why is the following supposed to be the case? $$S^e\equiv (D^d)^e\equiv D \pmod{N}$$

I see that if $D$ and $N$ are relatively primes, then Euler's formula can be used. But that means we can only sign a document $D$ that is relatively prime to the modulus $N$?

Comment: This is textbook RSA ( unfortunately decryption is sometimes called signature but it is not). To be secure RSA needs proper padding. RSA function works for any message. Here the dupes ( wait ...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does RSA work for any message M?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/does-rsa-work-for-any-message-m) and this is RSA-PSS [How does RSA signature verification work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9896/18298)

Comment: $S\equiv D^d\pmod N$ does not uniquely define an integer $S$ from $D$, $d$ and $N$. What does is $S=D^d\bmod N$, adding that $0\le S<N$. In actual RSA signature, $D$ is not the signed document; it's a value in $[0,N)$ reversibly determined from the hash of the document and perhaps a random value (incidentally, that makes it virtually certain $D$ and $N$ are relatively prime). See [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=31) and [RSASSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=27) for how it's really done.